# How to prevent model property from being validated in mvc controller in AspNet Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an MVC controller action that receives a complex type with some lists of employees. In my custom model binder I separate the employees into accepted and rejected and return the ExcelEmployeeModel

```
public class ExcelEmployeeModel
{
    [Required] public String Description { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Accepted { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> RejectedEmployees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required] public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

It seems that AspNetCore is calling validate for each of the employees in the list and sending a BadRequest object back to the client if there are any rejected employees. Therefore, if there are any rejected employees the action is never executed.

How do I prevent a property such as RejectedEmployees from getting validated?

It would be nice to just be able to decorate my property with a custom attribute as follows:

```
[NoValidation]
public List<Employee> RejectedEmployees {get;set;}
```

This ValidationAttribute is the reason for the employee items being validated and the bad request is being returned from there.

```
// Conifguration file StartUp.cs
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelAttribute());
}

// Custom validation attribute class
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the action supposed to receive the data but it does not.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] ExcelEmployeeModel model)
{
 ... 
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens automatically. Please post your action's code and how you are calling it / with what data

Comment: I added a little bit to hint to a possible reason @Camilo_Terevinto

Comment: The action doesn't get fired so its code will not help at all. There is a custom model binder that runs for the data posted to the server in the form of an excel file which produces the ExcelEmployeeModel.  The list of reject employees gets validated internally and never reaches the action. I can verify this by deleting the [RequiredAttribute] from the validated properties. When I do that the action gets the data as expected in the model variable.

Comment: Well, you either disable `ValidateModelAttribute` (or enable it per controller/action) or you remove the required attribute from the models

Comment: By the way, I put a break point in the ValidateModelAttribute  and the ModelState validation never failed.

Answer (score 0):

The following will probably be my final solution.

```
public class NoValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public static void RemoveValidation(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Get the properties that contain the [NoValidationAttribute]
        var properties = context.ActionArguments.First().Value.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(a =>
                a.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<NoValidationAttribute>().Any());

        // For each of the properties remove the modelstate errors.
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            foreach (var key in context.ModelState.Keys.Where(k =>
                k.StartsWith($"{property.Name}["))) // Item index is part of key [
            {
                context.ModelState.Remove(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my ValidationModelAttribute is now as follows:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    NoValidationAttribute.RemoveValidation(context);

    // Finally validation passes for properties using the [NoValidateAttribute]
    if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
    }
}

// Model using the NoValidationAttribute
public class ExcelEmployeeModel
{
    [Required] public String Description { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Accepted { get; set; }
    [NoValidation]
    public List<Employee> RejectedEmployees { get; set; }
}
```